# Android display data from json to spinner and textview

Tags: android, json

Hello everybody I want to display data from my server and display theme on my spinner and text view. So far what I've tried is displaying them on my spinner. But I don't have a clue how to display them on textview.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
private ArrayList<Verse> versesList;
versesList = new ArrayList<Verse>();

// DownloadJSON AsyncTask
private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Create a progressdialog
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ALARM.this);
        // Set progressdialog title
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Downloading Verses");
        // Set progressdialog message
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        // Show progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Create the array 
        // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given website URL in JSONfunctions.class

        ServiceHandler jsonParser = new ServiceHandler();
        String result;

        lang = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();

        if(lang.equals("en")){
            result = jsonParser.makeServiceCall(URLENGLISH, ServiceHandler.GET);
        } else  {
            result = jsonParser.makeServiceCall(URLTAGALOG, ServiceHandler.GET);
        }


        try {
            JSONArray jr = new JSONArray(result);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + result);

            for (int i = 0; i < jr.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject catObj = jr.getJSONObject(i); //(JSONObject) jr.get(i);
                Verse cat = new Verse(catObj.getInt("verse_id"), 
                        catObj.getString("verse_title"));

                    versesList.add(cat);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
} 

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
        // Close the progressdialog
        if (mProgressDialog.isShowing())
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        populateSpinner();
    }
}

/**
 * Adding spinner data
 * */
private void populateSpinner() {
    List<String> lables = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < versesList.size(); i++) {
        lables.add(versesList.get(i).getName());
    }

    // Creating adapter for spinner
    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);

    // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
    spinnerAdapter
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // attaching data adapter to spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
}
```

Does anybody know how to achieve this? Your help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you need to use a custom adapter and display it in a listview

Comment: @Raghunandan can you provide some sample implementation of that? No. My requirement is to display it on spinner and textview, not in listview

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/.

Comment: @Raghunandan I can display it in the listview but my requirement is to display them on spinner and textview.. THose views are separate

Comment: @Raghunandan and when I change the spinner selected Item, the value of textview should be changed as well

Comment: have a list of type string add all your string values to the string list and set adapter accordingly. you want to display all json in a single textview

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46062/discussion-between-dunkey-and-raghunandan)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
So far what I've tried is displaying them on my spinner. But I don't have a clue how to display them on textview.
```

To display the selected item in textview you need to get the position of selected item

```
 int position = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
```

Then

```
String content = versesList.get(position).getContent().toString();
```

Then

```
textView.setText(content);
```